# Как в 2D массиве Numpy заменить значения по списку индексов?

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

Варианты с циклами не подходят, слишком долгие, так как в реальности размеры массивов будут большие.

```
import numpy

a = numpy.zeros((10, 5)).astype('uint8')
print(a)
b = numpy.array([[3,2],[4,1],[2,3],[1,2]])
# b = b.tolist()
# a.put(b,1)
a[b] = 1
print(a)
```

Результат с использованием `a.put(b,1)` и `a[b] = 1` одинаковый и не тот что мне нужен.

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Если массив переконвертировать в список `# b = b.tolist()`, то выдает ошибку:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 4 were indexed
```

Необходимый результат:

```
[[0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Как это сделать не используя циклы?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490961/replace-2d-numpy-array-elements-based-on-2d-indexes

Comment: @СергейКох Спасибо! Такой способ мне больше подходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формируем индексы в `b` в виде кортежа, где первым элементом - массив/список/кортеж индексов строк, вторым - массив/список/кортеж индексов столбцов (для 2D).

```
a = np.zeros((10, 5)).astype('uint8')
b = ((0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 1, 0))
a[b] = 1
print(a)
```

```
[[0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Проблему решает, но в моем случае больше подходит решение из комментария к вопросу: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490961/replace-2d-numpy-array-elements-based-on-2d-indexes